# I want to check the contents off multiple folders and logs the results with one batch file

Tags: file, logging, batch-file, directory

I have a running program that batch processes a heap of documents and places them in a DMS. When the program has finished processing each document, it places it in another folder. It then can either be placed in a sub folder called succeeded or in a sub folder called failed. The documents that were not successful uploaded to the DMS are placed in the sub folder failed. This process is repeated every day, so each day two new folder are created, named "importresults_%datetime\succeeded" and "importresults_%datetime\failed".

I want to create another batch file that each day checks the newly created sub folder "importresults_%datetime\failed" on its content. For each document in it I want the batch file to log it.

I have tried something like this to check if a file exists in a certain folder to start with, but this does not work.

```
CheckFileExist.bat >> C:\CFE_log.txt

for /f %%i in C:\Dfolder do (

IF not EXIST echo %%i >> C:\CFE_log.txt
pause
```

This seems to keep on looping in the log file.

Comment: You need something after EXIST. Either a filename or a variable containing a filename.

Comment: Also, you want to change your for to: `for /f %%i in ('dir C:\Dfolder /b /a-d') do (` Add /s to the dir switches if Dfolder contains subfolders that you want processed also.

Comment: I changed the for statement like Matt suggested. I also changed the EXIST statement by adding %%i or *.txt. Both still not successful.

Comment: what format has `%datetime` ?

Answer (score 0):

> #### I want to create another batch file that each day checks the newly created sub folder `"importresults_%datetime\failed"` on its content. For each document in it I want the batch file to log it.

#### Batch

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir "C:\Dfolder" /a-d /b') do (
   echo %%A>>C:\CFE_log.txt
)
pause
```

Just change the "C:\Dfolder" to whatever directory you want to list.

#### What?

What is the purpose of this line `CheckFileExist.bat >> C:\CFE_log.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this from the main folder it will pick the latest folder if the folders sort by name, and then create a list of the files (in a file called `name of folder - failed files.txt` ) and place it in the same folder you launch this batch file from.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^|find /i "failed" ^|sort') do (
echo found "%%a"
set "folder=%%a"
set "name="%%~nxa"
)
echo setting variable to "%folder%"
echo getting list of failed files into "%name% - failed files.txt"
dir "%folder%" /b /a-d >"%name% - failed files.txt"
echo done.
```